# Select a button having multiple classes in capybara

Tags: capybara, capybara-webkit

I want to select button inside the first div 
Following is the code using

```
    <div id="1">
    <button class="button btcls bns" data-dismiss="modal">create</button>
</div>
```

I used following method to select that button'

```
    xpath('//btcls').click
```

But no one is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
within("#1") do
  click_button("create")
end
```